# Don't understand result of numpy.correlate on time-series

Tags: python, numpy, time-series

I'm trying to model a time-series that maps DateTime into stock price.  Here is the time-series (gaps correspond to NaN prices):
[image]

There are 126 DateTime:Price points.  I then tried applying `numpy.correlate` but the results I get are puzzling:

[image]

Puzzling:

1. The values are very large (1E17-1E19); I thought they should be in the range [ -1, 1 ].
2. I understand the peak at 126 (the length of the data), but shouldn't there be one at 0 and at 252?

Comment: What exactly did you pass as arguments to `numpy.correlate`? Did you read and understand https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.correlate.html?

Answer (score 1):

Please read the documentation of `np.correlate`. From what I can tell, it seems you have passed `mode='same'`. Maximum correlation will be at  `len(data)/2`.

Quick example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

stocks = np.abs(np.random.normal(0, 100, size=252))
stockscor = np.correlate(stocks, stocks, mode='same')

plt.plot(stockscor)
plt.show()
```

[image: example output]